# Encrypt a column using a symmetric key and column remains encrypted

Tags: sql-server, encryption

I am trying to create a view from a table in SQL Server and apply encryption on a specific column. This was done successfully while the symmetric key was open using the code below:

```
CREATE VIEW [abc].[Taxid_vw] AS
with Encrypt as (
    SELECT [AccountName]
        , ENCRYPTBYKEY(KEY_GUID('EncryptionKey')
        , CAST([Value] AS Varchar)) encrypted
    FROM [extacrt].[dbo].[Property] q
 )
 Select * from Encrypt;
 GO
```

The problem is when I run the view again in another instance, the encrypted column returns a NULL. How can I keep the column encrypted always

Comment: Just a little aside, don't use  CAST([Value] AS Varchar) without a size, should be varchar(30) or whatever, since otherwise your values gets truncated

Answer (score 0):

SQL Sever encryption keys are structured hierarchically from the SQL instance to the database. To decipher a database restored on another instance, the initial hierarchy must be recomposed. Otherwise, it would be too simple, like locking your car and leaving the keys in the lock! (which some badly designed RDBMS like PostGreSQL or MySQL do...)
[SQL Server Encryption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/sql-server-encryption?view=sql-server-ver16)
Read the articles devoted to this subject on the Microsoft site...

Comment: thanks for the answer. Pls, I'm trying to run this encryption and allow AWS glue (ingestion) to pull the account name and encrypted record into Snowflake. Is there a way I can ensure the encrypted data remains in the view?